# Cfengine vs Chef

Tags: configuration-management, chef-infra, cfengine

What are the differences in term of features between Cfengine and Chef?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chef has much greater integration with "cloud" VM hosting providers, and a greater amount of recipe sharing than CFEngine.

CFEngine takes less resources when it runs, and runs on a much greater range of computing environments from embedded devices to supercomputers, and on a lot more operating systems -- it's just a few small C binaries and a couple of C libraries, so it is more portable.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Chef FAQ](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/FAQ):

> **How is it different than Cfengine?**
>
> It bears very little in common with Cfengine, other than embracing Single Copy Nirvana.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much about Chef, just been reading their web site, and I'm quite familiar with Cfengine; so take my answer with a grain of salt.

From what I gathered, the main difference is that Cfengine runs on both Linux/Unixes and Windows, while Chef only support Linux/Unixes.

Comment: As of version 0.8.14, Chef has preliminary support for Windows: http://www.opscode.com/blog/2010/05/07/chef-0-8-14-release/

Comment: Update: Opscode supports Windows with the latest versions of Chef. There's an MSI package, "windows" and "powershell" cookbooks that bring a number of Windows-specific primitives, more in this press release: http://www.opscode.com/press-releases/opscode-delivers-cloud-infrastructure-automation-to-windows-environments/